# Prestashop 1.7.6.5 - Email Translation Problem -> Page not Found

Tags: prestashop

i'm using Prestashop 1.7.6.5 and i'm able to update any product and any page via backoffice, but I can't update the email translation. The page keeps loading and after long time it says page not found.I have no errors in the log files and when i turn on debug mode it doesn't show errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is actually a bug from this prestashop version:

https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/16294

The new version is currently on beta